# Why the error only be reported on the second element and how can I solve it?

Tags: c++

I try to build a char array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    static const char array1[] = {"green", "red","red", "green", "green"};

}
```

I would expect this to work, but I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: `{"green", "red","red", "green", "green"}` is not an array of characters

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the question has been modified to be quite clear (although the research hasn't been made). There's code, an expected output and the error message that it yields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to initialize the [`char` array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Character_arrays) with **multiple** [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) which decay to `const char*`. So either use characters in your [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
const char array1[] = { 'g', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g' };
```

or change the array signature to `const char*`:

```
const char* array1[] = { "green", "red", "red", "green", "green" };
```

or simply use a [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type:

```
std::string array1[] = { "green", "red","red", "green", "green" };
```

or even better, a vector of strings:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = { "green", "red", "red", "green", "green" };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an array of chars. Its an Array of strings.

You could write

`static const char* array1[] = {"green", "red","red", "green", "green"};`

or

`static const std::string array1[] = {"green", "red","red", "green", "green"};`

Also the error is on the second entry because `"green"` is an array of chars.

Comment: I guess the `static` wasnt intentionally (maybe also the `const`). And imho the first option should be a `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @tobi303 there's no need to use a vector if the size won't change

Comment: @M.M sure, then it is an `std::array`